# React change className on basis of props

Tags: reactjs

I have to give a give dynamically to my rows of table according to the data.

If my `this.props.data.status=='Succcess'`  Then the row should be in green color.

If my `this.props.data.status=='Failure'`  Then the row should be in red color.

If my `this.props.data.status=='Inprogress'`  Then the row should be in yellow color.

I was able to do it in angular with `ng-class="{red: t.status == 'Failure',green: t.status == 'Success',amber: t.status == 'Inprogress'}"`
Can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways you can do this, perhaps the most simple would be creating an object to map a `status` to a `className`:

```
const statusToClassName = {
    Success: "green",
    Inprogress: "blue",
    Failure: "red"
};
```

And then in your `render` method:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className={statusToClassName[this.props.data.status]}>
            ...
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the classnames package and use it like

```
import classnames from 'classnames'
```

and then in render

```
render() {
     const {data: {status}} = this.props;
     const rowClassNames = classnames({
         red: status == 'Failure',
         green: status == 'Success',
         amber: status == 'Inprogress'
     })

     return (
         <div className={rowClassNames}>XYZ</div>
     )

}
```

Comment: classnames is quite a useful package when it comes to applying multiple classes or applying classes conditionally. Glad it helped